# How to use local default image for django-gravatar?

Tags: django, gravatar

I am using django-gravatar and I am wondering how to display a local image to use as a default image. Is there a way to do so?

I have read in the docs to use `GRAVATAR_DEFAULT_IMAGE`, but it does not seem to work specifying the path to the image within the `static/` directory. Is it only for online images from other websites?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am using the following configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
GRAVATAR_DEFAULT_IMAGE = STATIC_URL + 'img/StartMyProjects_100.png'
```

Hack finally used to solve the problem:

```
<img class="media-object" src="
{% if profile.gravatar_email %}
    {% gravatar_for_email profile.gravatar_email %}
{% else %}
    /static/img/StartMyProjects_100.png
{% endif %}"
alt="{{ profile.full_name }}">
```

Comment: Give us the line in `config` in which you set `GRAVATAR_DEFAULT_IMAGE`. Make sure this url is reachable. Try putting a link to the image as a static asset right next to the gravatar, and click it to verify it is served properly

Comment: This is not what I am asking for! I already know how to display an image for a given user/email. What I want is to display a default image.

Comment: I have edded the configuration I am using in my settings.py @catherine I know I could modify the library or use custom template tags, but I would prefer not to do so if possible! :)

Comment: Ok I read the documentation of gravatar. It is said to use d=  or default= parameter, not GRAVATAR_DEFAULT_IMAGE?

Comment: Yes, this is what this variable in settings.py is supposed to do. You set the value for this variable and the library builds the URL for you. In fact, django-avatar is building the following bad url for the local image: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e/?default=%2Fstatic%2Fimg%2FStartMyProjects_100.png&amp;s=80". Here you can see how default is used, but the url should only be: "/static/img/StartMyProjects_100.png"

Comment: +1 Good job you finally fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks, I hope this helps someone else! :)

Comment: Answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, as stated in the edited question, I actually used an if-else (in Django). Maybe someone knows a better way to do so, but this worked for me!

```
<img class="media-object" src="
{% if profile.gravatar_email %}
    {% gravatar_for_email profile.gravatar_email %}
{% else %}
    /static/img/StartMyProjects_100.png
{% endif %}"
alt="{{ profile.full_name }}">
```